# Find percentage of occurrence using shell script

Tags: linux, awk

I have a file with numbers like this:

0.122
1.44
5.44

I want to write a shell script that will give me percentage for the following criteria:

- % of data less than 0.1
- % of data between 0.1 and 0.2
- % of data between 0.2 and 0.5
- % of data greater than 1

I am trying with awk, but not able to get it through...

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this would do:

```
awk ' 
  $1 < 0.1 { c[0]++ } 
  $1 < 0.2 { c[1]++ } 
  $1 < 0.5 { c[2]++ } 
  $1 > 1   { c[3]++ } 
  END {
    c[2] -= c[1];
    c[1] -= c[0];
    t = c[0] + c[1] + c[2] + c[3];
    print (c[0]/t) * 100, (c[1]/t) * 100, (c[2]/t) * 100, (c[3]/t) * 100
  }'  input
```

Comment: Seems cleaner to do `0 <= $1 && $1 < 0.1`, etc than to subtract off at the end.

Comment: Thanks Perreal for the answer

Answer (score 0):

```
cat file | python -c 'import numpy,sys; a=[float(l.strip()) for l in sys.stdin];b=numpy.histogram(a,bins = [0,.1,.2,.5,1,max(a)])[0];print [x*100/sum(b) for x in b]'
```